A conjecture on quadratic residues
Given $p$ is an odd prime, let $a_1, a_2,\dots, a_p$ be integers such that $p\mid (a_1+a_2+\dots+a_p)$ and that ,
$$
\frac{a_{j+1}+a_{j+2}+\dots+a_{j+i}}{i}\quad \text{is a quadratic residue of $p$ (not zero)},
$$
for every $i,j\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $1\le i\le p-1$, $0\le j\le p-i$. Here the denominator $i$ denotes the inverse of $i \pmod p$.
Is it true  that $a_1\equiv a_2\equiv\dots\equiv a_p\pmod p$?

What have you tried?

Also, the question should be clarified a bit. Does the denominator $i$ implicitly mean that $a_{j+1}+\ldots+a_{j+i}$ is divisible by $i$, or is $1/i$ to be read as the integer $\bar i$ with $i\bar i\equiv1\pmod{p}$? In addition, some context of this question would be fine.

An old question in my question list when reading some of the GTMs. Sorry for the vague description, I will try to check out that ASAP.

$\def\FF{\mathbb{F}}$The answer is "yes".
This question is a cleverly disguised way of asking for the automorphism group of the Paley digraph and follows from Proposition 1 in a paper of our own Peter Mueller. To see the connection, choose an element $b_0$ of $\FF_p$ arbitrarily and put
$$b_i = b_0 + a_1+a_2+\dotsb + a_i.$$
Since $\sum_{i=1}^p a_i = 0$, we have $b_0 = b_p$; since $a_{j+1}+a_{j+2} + \dotsb + a_{j+i}$ is assumed to be nonzero for $1 \leq i \leq p-1$, we have $b_j \neq b_{j+i}$. So $(b_1, b_2, \dotsc, b_p)$ is a permutation of $(1,2,\dotsc, p)$.
The condition on this permutation is that $b_j - b_i$ is a quadratic residue if and only if $j-i$ is a quadratic residue. In Mueller's result, take $U$ to be the set of quadratic residues. Then Mueller's result says that $b_i = ri+s$ for some $r$, $s \in \FF_p$, and $a_1=a_2=\cdots = a_p = r$.
See this old answer for other ways of computing the automorphism group of the Paley graph.

"Cleverly disguised"!!!??? :) :)  A hilarious turn of phrase, given the context. :)  True, naivete is often a clever, if subconscious, disguise. :)  I did laugh out loud. :)
